# Filter select-options through another select-option value

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

My target is to filter `<select name="team">` by using a JS function from `<select name="unit">`. Team is a many-to-one relationship with Unit so filtering it would be much more safer option. I've list down the tables and my test codes below:

Team-Unit pivot table

`-------------------`

`Team --------- Unit`

`A ------------- 1`

`B ------------- 1`

`C ------------- 1`

`D ------------- 2`

`E ------------- 2`

`F ------------- 3`

`-------------------`

```
<select name="unit" class="form-control" id="unit" onchange="refreshTeam()" required />
    <option value="" selected disabled>SELECT UNIT</option>
    @foreach ($units as $unit)
        <option value="{{$unit->id}}">{{ $unit->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>


<select name="team" class="form-control" id="team" required />
    <option value="" selected disabled>SELECT TEAM</option>
    @foreach ($teams as $team)
        <option value="{{$team->id}}">{{ $team->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

Here's my try on refreshTeam(), but I'm pretty sure this is wrong or needs improvement

```
function refreshTeam() {
        var team = document.getElementById("team");
        var unit = document.getElementById("unit");

        <?php
            $unit = 'document.getElementById("unit").value';

            $team_unit = \DB::table('teams')
                            ->leftJoin('team_unit', 'teams.id', '=', 'team_unit.team_id')
                            ->leftJoin('units', 'units.id', '=', 'team_unit.unit_id')
                            ->select('teams.*')
                            ->where($unit, '=', 'team_unit.unit_id')
                            ->get();
            dd($team_unit);
        ?>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The refreshTeam function should call `GET /unit/1/teams` this will return all teams related to unit 1.

- Add the `/unit/{unit}/teams` route
- In this route fetch the related teams and return it as json
- In your refreshTeam use ajax or axios to call the endpoint with the related unit
- Populate the related teams in the select